# How to add a reset after 4 clock cycles in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to verify the output for 4 bit SAR logic.  So far this is my schematic:
[image]

These are my resullts so far:
[image]

I am trying to add more to the PWL, which is what I assume I have to do, but the outputs aren't resetting after 4 clock cycles.

**EDIT**:I now changed the PWL at the CLK to a pulse 
[image]
These are now the results, where the first and last bit aren't showing the expected results:
[image]

These are the values on each component:
[image]

Comment: Are you making use of the builtin parameter `td` (and/or `tau`, for example)? If no, add it, if not, don't make them all the same, add slight variations (e.g. `td=50n`, `td=51n`, etc).

Comment: Everything on the schematic has td=10p, adding slight variations to each flip flop didn't change the results.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that for a D flip flop, you'd have to bring the CLR line high for all flops to reset them. You could do this with logic from the last flop, or a PWL source.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried having the CLR line high, but now there isn't any output at all.  For the PWL source connected to reset, I am not sure what to do with it for it to reset.  I am able to get the first 4 clock cycles, but after that, it won't reset no matter how many additional PWL points I add.

Comment: @Tyrone Why do you say "the PWL source connected to *reset*"? Is it just because you labeled the net as `reset`? What reasons could you have for not using the dedicated `CLR` (`CLEAR`, `RESET`) pin, and instead using the `D` (`DATA`) pin?